# Overlay of annotation circle in Map - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to add a circle with a certain radius in `Map` with `SwiftUI` only. I want to be able to show a circular overlay in the `Map` with e.g. 1 km. This is a picture what I want to achieve:

[image]

The problem with the code below, is that the circle has a fixed size on the map:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    static let usersLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.0929779694589, longitude: 5.084964426384347)

    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: ContentView.usersLocation,
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)
    )
    let annotations = [CurrentUsersAnnotation()]

    
    var body: some View {
        Map(
            coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: annotations) { _ in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: ContentView.usersLocation) {
                    Circle()
                            .strokeBorder(Color.red, lineWidth: 4)
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                }
            }
    }
}

struct CurrentUsersAnnotation: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() // Always unique on map
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Is there a SwiftUI-only fix? I am not looking for UIKit answers, I want to do it fully in SwiftUI.

Comment: You can't. Overlays aren't supported in SwiftUI, only UIKit.

Answer (score 4):

Overlays aren't supported but you can easily size your `View`/`Circle` by figuring out the ratio between the `View` and the `span`

First, since you want kilometers you can calculate the distance between the upper and lower edge (latitude span) of the region.

```
extension MKCoordinateRegion{
    ///Identify the length of the span in meters north to south
    var spanLatitude: Measurement<UnitLength>{
        let loc1 = CLLocation(latitude: center.latitude - span.latitudeDelta * 0.5, longitude: center.longitude)
        let loc2 = CLLocation(latitude: center.latitude + span.latitudeDelta * 0.5, longitude: center.longitude)
        let metersInLatitude = loc1.distance(from: loc2)
        return Measurement(value: metersInLatitude, unit: UnitLength.meters)
    }
}
```

using `GeometryReader` you can get the `height` of the `View`/`Map`, then the ratio. Once you have the size per meter just multiply to get kilometer.

```
//Size per meter
let ratio = (geo.size.height/region.spanLatitude.value)
//Size per kilometer
let kilometerSize = ratio * 1000
```

Then use the `kilometerSize` in the `frame`.

It is likely not be a perfect kilometer given there are likely inconsistencies between the `View` and the `Map` but it is probably pretty close. If you can find something that is a known kilometer you can test it out.

```
struct ScaledAnnotationView: View {
    static let usersLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.0929779694589, longitude: 5.084964426384347)
    
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: ScaledAnnotationView.usersLocation,latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000
    )
    let annotations = [CurrentUsersAnnotation()]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        //Get the size of the frame for scale
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            Map(
                coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: annotations) { _ in
                    MapAnnotation(coordinate: ScaledAnnotationView.usersLocation) {
                            //Size per kilometer or any unit, just change the converted unit.
                            let kilometerSize = (geo.size.height/region.spanLatitude.converted(to: .kilometers).value)
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                        //Keep it a circle
                            .frame(width: kilometerSize, height: kilometerSize)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is  Google maps distance measurement for confirmation of measurement

[image]

Comment: Not a perfect solution, if you zoom in enough, the circle will disappear, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: @J.Doe disappear as in you zoom into the circle? I didn't think the color was a part of the question. Just use fill instead of stroke.

Comment: @J.Doe I think I found what you mean. It looks like the `Map` gets rid of the `Circle`/Annotation if the center is a certain amount off screen. I don't think there is a way around that. It is likely a performance thing

Comment: One workaround might be to limit the zoom but since there is no built in way there will probably be jumping.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 17, this is now supported. Apple has a more in-depth tutorial on their website https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10043/. An example from the video:

```
Map {
    MapCircle(center: someCLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: 100)
        .foregroundStyle(.cyan.opacity(0.5))
        .mapOverlayLevel(level: .aboveRoads)
}
```