# SwiftUI Make map Anntation scale correctly

Tags: swift, dictionary, swiftui, mapkit

im making an app where it shows a circle around your location, the circle is set to be 200 pixels width and height. But when you zoom in or out of the app the circle stays the same and doesnt shrink/grow acordingly.

Heres the code for the map:

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region,
                    interactionModes: .all,
                    showsUserLocation: true,
                    annotationItems: MapLocations,
                    annotationContent: { location in
                    MapAnnotation(
                        coordinate: location.coordinate,
                        content: {
                            Circle()
                                .fill(.red)
                                .opacity(0.5)
                                .frame(width: CGFloat(setWidth), height: CGFloat(setHeight))
                                .animation(.default)
                                .overlay(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: CGFloat(radius))
                                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 5)
                                )
                            
                        }
                    )
                }
                )
```

Is there a way to make it set the width of the circle to 100metres instead of 200 pixels?

Thanks!

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine How do i apply that into my code? Ive tried to add it but it doesnt work.

Comment: Tested the linked answer, all seems to work for me.
You will have to copy and paste the appropriate code, and use it like in
 `ScaledAnnotationView` of the answer. It seems to be basic. Don't forget the
 `extension MKCoordinateRegion`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Would you care to try re create the answer explaining it a bit more, im still sort of a begginer and always struggle copying and pasteing it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this fully functional code example, from the linked answer at: [Overlay of annotation circle in Map - SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71024399/overlay-of-annotation-circle-in-map-swiftui)

Since I test this in mac Catalyst, I use the + and - keys to zoom.

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import SwiftUI


struct ScaledAnnotationView: View {
    static let usersLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.0929779694589, longitude: 5.084964426384347)
    
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: ScaledAnnotationView.usersLocation,latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000
    )
    let annotations = [CurrentUsersAnnotation()]
    
    var body: some View {
        //Get the size of the frame for scale
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: annotations) { _ in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: ScaledAnnotationView.usersLocation) {
                    //Size per kilometer or any unit, just change the converted unit.
                    let kilometerSize = (geo.size.height/region.spanLatitude.converted(to: .kilometers).value)
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
                        .frame(width: kilometerSize, height: kilometerSize)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScaledAnnotationView()
    }
}

struct CurrentUsersAnnotation: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() // Always unique on map
}

extension MKCoordinateRegion{
    ///Identify the length of the span in meters north to south
    var spanLatitude: Measurement<UnitLength>{
        let loc1 = CLLocation(latitude: center.latitude - span.latitudeDelta * 0.5, longitude: center.longitude)
        let loc2 = CLLocation(latitude: center.latitude + span.latitudeDelta * 0.5, longitude: center.longitude)
        let metersInLatitude = loc1.distance(from: loc2)
        return Measurement(value: metersInLatitude, unit: UnitLength.meters)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, thats good, how do i make the circle go around users location?

Comment: ask another question about this, you may get help from someone more interested than me. Good coding...